# Why vTaskList and vTaskListTasks not working on FreeRTOS 11.0.1?

Tags: c, cmake, embedded, freertos, raspberry-pi-pico

I am trying to debug a FreeRTOS application scheduling on a RP2040 Raspberry Pico using the functions vTaskList or vTaskLists and can't get any output on my serial line (minicom).

This is my `main()` on the source code:

```c
    char pcWriteBuffer[0xFFFF];
    stdio_init_all();
    if (cyw43_arch_init()) {
        return -1;
    }

    xTaskCreate(external_led_task, "External_LED_Task", 256, NULL, 3, NULL);
    xTaskCreate(onboard_led_task, "Onboard_LED_Task", 256, NULL, 3, NULL);
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    vTaskList(pcWriteBuffer);
    printf("%s\n", pcWriteBuffer);




    while(1){};
```

My serial output via USB is already enabled on `CMakeLists.txt` and i have tested other printfs on the same code, showed properly on minicom.

```c
pico_enable_stdio_usb(${ProjectName} 1)
pico_enable_stdio_uart(${ProjectName} 0)
```

I have already defined the two `FreeRTOSConfig.h` macros required to use these functions:

```c
#define configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY                1
#define configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS    1
```

I also tried using `vTaskListTasks` this way:

```c
    char pcWriteBuffer[1024];
    vTaskListTasks(pcWriteBuffer, 1024);
    printf("%s\n", pcWriteBuffer);
```

I tried creating a task only for the `vTaskList` or `vTaskListTasks`, I don't know why but the program don't even run when I try this, tried the same task priority for all tasks.

Comment: why do you think that printf will output to USB?

Comment: Crawl before you walk ... The _first_ thing that I verify for things like this is debug/UART output. Start with a simple `printf("hello world\n");` immediately after `stdio_init_all();` UART config depends on parameters (e.g. baud rate, etc.). Also, the cable and what UART program you're using on your development system. All have to match up. Also, if the UART cable is USB-to-UART, that can have some additional issues.

Comment: @gulpr  because as i said on the post, i already tested other printfs on the same code...

Comment: @CraigEstey as i said on the post, i already tested if the printf is working properly on the usb output and it is.

Comment: Okay, we may have missed that. But, there is some code missing. Even if `pcWriteBuffer` is an empty string, you should see an extra newline. Do you? Do you get UART output _after_ doing the `cyw43_arch_init` call. What I do is pepper the code with [debug] `printf` calls. Are there any in the task functions? From the documentation for `vTaskListTasks`, we have: _`configUSE_TRACE_FACILITY` and `configUSE_STATS_FORMATTING_FUNCTIONS` must be defined as 1 in FreeRTOSConfig.h for this function to be available._ Are these set? Maybe we need to see your `FreeRTOSConfig.h`

Comment: Maybe you could loop on `vTaskListTasks` for a few iterations [to allow time for the tasks to register themselves?]. You could keep a copy of the buffer and print it if/whenever it changes. You could do `strcpy(pcWriteBuffer,"not a valid response");` before the call and see if that comes out. This would show whether `vTaskListTasks` does _anything_ to the buffer (even forcing it to an empty string).

Comment: @CraigEstey man i said that, i defined these macros as 1. And not, dont even a new line is being printed

Answer (score 3):

The buffer `pcWriteBuffer` is a 64KB object on the stack, on a part with only 256KB of RAM.  Apart from being far larger than reasonably necessary for the task list (the documentation suggests 40 bytes per task), it is also larger than your likely main stack size, which will typically be a few KB.  Make the buffer smaller and declare it `static`.  `vTaskList()` blocks the scheduler, so there are no reentrancy issues with using a `static`.

However that is not the reason for your issue (although it is an issue). The primary issue is here:

```
    vTaskStartScheduler();

    vTaskList(pcWriteBuffer);
    printf("%s\n", pcWriteBuffer);
```

`vTaskList()` will never be called because `vTaskStartScheduler()` never returns as the documentation states:

> vTaskStartScheduler() will only return if there is insufficient RTOS heap available
> to create the idle or timer daemon tasks.

It only makes sense to call `vTaskList` from a task context (or after creating tasks and before calling `vTaskStartScheduler()` perhaps, though that serves little purpose)

Comment: already tried calling before `vTaskStarScheduler()`, reducing a lot the size of the buffer too (i tried only one time with 0xFFFF for a test), no diff.

Comment: Reducing the buffer size may not help if it is still too large.  How much stack have you allocated?  On a part this size a typical stack size would be between 256 bytes and 2KB.  Make it static ant the potential problem goes away.

Comment: The reason I suggested it serves no purpose before the scheduler is started is that the documentation does not specify whether the list is of tasks started or created. If the former there will be nothing to list, if the latter, what is the point, you already know what you created at that point. You need to run this function in a task context. Perhaps in response to some input (serial or a button perhaps).  The reason the code shown cannot work is that it is unreachable in normal cases.  If you use it correctly and it still does not work, that is a different problem and needs a new question.